# Blank screen after killing the android process

Tags: java, android, process

I am developing an android app that uses a service to continuously for the broadcast purpose. I want to provide an option of force stop in my app. For that purpose I am using 
`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`. which is working fine.

I have three java files..

**Home.java** for start and force stop
**MainActivity.java** to start and force stop service accordingly
And a service

I have invoked `killProcess` on force stop Onclick in MainActivity.

But the problem is, I am getting a blank white screen on killing.
Instead I want my *home screen* to be displayed. How can I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want tour activity to finish and move back to home screen.
you could use `system.exit(0)`.
to completely exit instead of killing.